# Image broken on retrieval from database

Tags: php, mysql, base64

Code:

```
$db = mysqli_connect("localhost","root","","photos");

if(isset($_POST['POST'])){

$image = addslashes($_FILES['image']['tmp_name']);
$image_name = addslashes($_FILES['image']['name']);
$image = file_get_contents($image);
$image = base64_encode($image);


$sql = "INSERT INTO imaag ( name ) VALUES ('$image')";
mysqli_query($db,$sql);
}
$res = mysqli_query($db,"SELECT * from imaag");
```

and the div in which i'm getting images is:

```
<div>
    <?php 
    while ($row = mysqli_fetch_array($res)) {

    echo '<img 
 src="data:image/jpeg;base64,"'.base64_encode($row['name']).'/>';
    }?>
</div>
```

On retrieval the image is broken, and i don't know if the image is uploaded or not.What I think is that it isn't uploading. Uploading part has some problem.

Comment: Can you please check the database column first?

Comment: Please check my answer, use base64decode instead of encode.

Comment: That didn't work, showing some garbage value! @DarshanJain

Comment: @campaigner    check image is uploaded & inserted in table column.

Comment: Your image stored as already base64 encoded. Why encode it __again__ when outputting?

Comment: [BLOB - 64 KiB]
    [BLOB - 60 KiB] 
    [BLOB - 46.2 KiB]
It is showing like this in database.

Comment: @campaigner   image is inserted in table column or not?

Comment: [BLOB - 64 KiB] [BLOB - 60 KiB] [BLOB - 46.2 KiB] It is showing like this in database @MohitKumar

Comment: Your are storing image directly into database or path.If image is storing database which datatype ur using.

Comment: @campaigner first check image path is inserted in table or not? , & store in some directory or not ?. & BLOB is the datatype of that.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Because on retrieval You dont need `base64_encode` again. Just simply add string. change your `echo` as below:

```
 echo '<img 
 src="data:image/jpeg;base64,'.$row['name'].'"/>';
    }?>
```

Comment: decode the value but mentioned `base64` on src? will that work?

Comment: Are your images `jpeg`s? Outputing png with `data:image/jpeg` is incorrect.

Comment: @B.Desai  Also - __remove__ `"` because your `src` ends. It's the second reason why OP's code is not working.

Comment: Will you check now @campaigner88?

Comment: @campaigner88 explain reason for rejecting accepted answer and now accepting  incorrect answer `base64_encode` not needed in src

Answer (score 0):

Your **src="** has no closing **"**

Do this:

```
    echo '<img src="data:image/jpeg;base64,"'.base64_encode($row['name']).'"/>';
```